# EFS policy with Identifier other than * not working in EKS

Tags: amazon-efs

I have an EFS policy statement attached as below,

```
  policy_statements = [
    {
      sid     = "${var.cluster_name}"
      actions = ["elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
                 "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
                 "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite"]
      principals = [
        {
          type        = "AWS"
          identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/efs-test-role"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**If I use "*" for Identifier it works.**

I tried to create the role arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/efs-test-role with oidc Federation,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a ServiceAccount with annotation with this role,

eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/efs-test-role

When I created pods with EFS volume mount using Persistant volume, got error as,

```
Output: Could not start amazon-efs-mount-watchdog, unrecognized init system "aws-efs-csi-dri"
b'mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 127.0.0.1:/'
```

I even tried to follow https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/efs/latest/ug/manage-efs-utils-with-aws-sys-manager.html#configure-sys-mgr-iam-instance-profile to add **AmazonElasticFileSystemsUtils**  to EKS worker nodes instance profiles. But it still threw same error..

I am not sure what I am missing. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue, as well as @henrycarteruk and found the solution on AWS EFS Troubleshoot with mount issues:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-troubleshoot-efs-volume-mount-issues

Basically you have to add to the PersistentVolume or StorageClass that uses the PVC the `iam` mount option:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
kind: StorageClass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  name: efs-sc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
mountOptions:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 - tls                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 - iam
```

Then on the EFS Policy you can specify the IAM Role arn for the nodes. After that It worked instantly! I hope it helps the next person that runs into this issue!